# Возможно ли использовать готовые куки, чтобы не требовалась авторизация?

Tags: captcha, авторизация, cookie, парсер

Здравствуйте!

Нужно выполнить авторизацию на сайте с капчей и последующим парсингом, но не могу решить данную проблему, и возможно ли использовать готовые куки, чтобы не требовалась авторизация?

пример бы))

**Возможно ли использовать готовые куки, чтобы не требовалась авторизация?**

Comment: @romaaa32, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Готовый пример приводить не буду, но поделюсь ссылкой на пример формы регистрации и авторизации, там вы найдете ответы на свои вопросы. Вот ссылка [Форма регистрации](http://ruseller.com/lessons.php?rub_id=37&id=358)